# How to restrict Google Cloud OCR computing to within a region

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

We have a project where the data should not leave Canada for any reason because of some data residency requirements. Our project uses Google Compute OCR to scan documents. We have successfully created a project and within google cloud we have restricted the region to the Montreal data center (northeast-northeast1).

Wondering if there is a URL that will take us to that data center directly. Currently the URL we are accessing is vision.googleapis.com which appears to be located in US. So at some point our request crosses over to US even if our API key is generated within the Montreal data center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCP products are split into products available by region and global products. In the case for Cloud Vision API, it is currently listed as a [global product](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/) and accessing it regionally is currently not possible.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the clarification. I had seen the initial table in the page which listed the regions but was not clear what the second part of it being global product meant.